# Acumatica: Sales Order not show extension from BAccountExt

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I created a new field on my customer screen: UsrEmployeeID that is used to link an employee to a customer.
Then I displayed the field on my Sales Order:

[image]

This works as expected and pulls the data in from the customer master as I create the sales order.

The problem is when I reopen the Sales order after saving it doesn't show the field, the field is blank.
It looks like the Extenstion on the customer doesn't load. I have tested if I do n change on a onhold SO the field does get populated.

Is there a way to force the field to load its data on?

Before I get crucified for the below code I was testing in RowSelected. I will fix this if I get my code to work:

```
protected void SOOrder_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                var row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
                if (row is null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Customer customer = Base.customer.Current;
                BAccountExt bAccountExt = customer.GetExtension<BAccountExt>();


                cache.SetValueExt<BAccountExt.usrEmployeeID>(Base.customer.Current, bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID);
                bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID = bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PXTrace.WriteError("SOOrder_RowSelected: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Same result if you retrieve it with RowSelecting event?

Comment: On RowSelecting the BAccountExt is null. Looks like the BAccount(Ext) is only loaded after SOOrder

Comment: Why are you doing this... bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID = bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID;  The SetValueExt is also setting a field to itself.  Also, you are pulling BAccountExt from customer pulled from Base.customer.current.  You want to pull Customer based on e.Row.CustomerID instead of from Current.  You are right that Current isn't set yet because the row hasn't been "selected" yet.

Comment: Because the bAccountExt.UsrEmployeeID isn't populating and I saw that it was in the bAccountExt object in the event, my idea was to re-set it during runtime to see if I can get it to show. I don't think what I did above is anywhere close to the solution but it was an attempt to force the data to show.

Comment: If it is an unbound field that is not populated via the DAC, I believe you should be populating in the RowSelecting event.  If it is a bound field in the DAC, you should be populating when you maintain the customer record so that the value is saved accordingly.  If the field is not displaying data, confirm the value is actually in the DB.  What you described in behavior sounds suspiciously like it was an unbound field.  If these comments don't point you towards an answer, can you post the fields from the DAC(s)?  Customer inherits from BAccount, but I can't see any info about the custom field.

Comment: Could I suggest using an attribute on the SOOrder DAC field to retreive this value automatically?